# XHR2 отправка форм

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! На сайте очень много форм которые необходимо отправлять асинхронна. В данный момент я использую для этого XHR2 И для каждой формы у меня существует своя функция её отправки, поэтому получается очень много кода. Поэтому я хочу сделать одну функцию которая бы отправляла все запросы, но возникла проблема. Необходима чтобы функция также выполняла другую функцию которая бы работала с ответом с сервер.
Выглядит это приблизительно так:

Функция отправки форм:

> ```
> function SendForm(form,action,func) { //func - Имя функции которая должна выполнятся
>    var formData=new FormData(form),
>    xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
>
>   xhr.open('POST', action, true);
>   xhr.onload=function(e) {
>       /* вот тут должна быть функция обрабатывающая ответ (func) */
>   };
>   xhr.send(formData);
> }
> ```

Вызывается это вот так:

> ```
> <form onsubmit="SendForm(this,'адрес обработчика','Имя функции'); return false;">
> ```

Вот пример функции которая обрабатывает ответ:

> ```
> function myalert(response){ 
>  alert(response);
> };
> ```

Как заставить выполнятся функцию имя которой будет находится в переменной func и передавать в эту функцию response?

Возможно я как то за мудрил всё, если есть другие способы я только рад)

Comment: а в чем проблема ?

    xhr.onload=function(e) {
          func(e);
      };

но даже проще

    xhr.onload=func;

только надо не имя функции передавать а саму функцию.

     SendForm(this,'адрес обработчика',myalert)

лучше onsubmit в скрипте вешайте, а адрес обработчика в action храните, где ему и место.

Comment: Ответы, в ответы писать нужно, а не в коментарии!

Comment: А это комментарий, а не ответ! Потому как я не знаю правильно ли я вас понял.

Comment: Всё правильно!) Вот только ещё кое что... Сделал вот так xhr.onload=func; и функция function myalert(response){alert(response);}; В итоге в браузере алерт с надписью [object XMLhttpRequestProgressEvent], я что то никак не могу понять как мне до response добраться?